# Is it possible to setup Gulp in a distributed fashion?

Tags: gruntjs, npm, gulp

Here's what I want to do:

- Create a node package that features the following:

  - `gulpfile.js`
  - All gulp plugins, tasks, configs.
- Install this node package (referred to as "my-gulp" from here on) within an Angular app (referred to as "myApp" from here on) via `package.json` dependencies.
- `gulpfile.js` is copied into app root.
- All Gulp tasks can be run from app.

We currently have something similar setup with Grunt (although without the `Gruntfile.js` copy stuff). It works pretty well to have a common setup for each of our apps, but also several custom Bower components. Just have to bring it in as a dependency and it magically works.

The main issue I've run into so far is when I add my-gulp to myApp's dependencies, run the install, my-gulp comes in just fine, however the individual plugins (my-gulp dependencies) aren't seen. They're installed, but running something like `gulp default` or whatever shows them missing.

I've tried to setup Gulp dependencies (in my-gulp) under "dependencies" as opposed to "devDependencies", yet still not quite working.

---

Does anyone have any experience doing something like this?
Am I doing something blatantly stupid here?

Any help is awesome!

Thanks, everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way npm handles nested dependencies. When you install your "my-gulp" package, the directory tree looks like this:

```
| myApp
|-- node_modules
    |-- my-gulp
       |-- node_modules
           |-- gulp_dependency
```

As you can see, the dependencies of "my-gulp" are buried inside its own `node_modules` directory. `myApp` cannot access them.

You could use something like [npm-flatten](https://github.com/neenhouse/npm-flatten) to move those to the top directory. Otherwise you'll be forced to add each dependency to `myApp`'s package.json.

**Edit:**
As indicated in your gist, you can load the dependencies by path instead of package name. Instead of copying your gulpfile, simply require it from myApp, then load its dependencies with a relative path:

```
// myApp/gulpfile.js
require('my-gulp/gulpfile.js');

// my-gulp/gulpfile.js
var gulpDep = require('./node_modules/gulp-dependency');
```

Note: This won't work if you use `npm dedupe`.

Comment: Here's a Gist of what we're doing to deal with that problem in our "my-grunt" setup: https://gist.github.com/willpracht/189f99761cad4e22ca25. I made an attempt to mimic this as best I could, but wasn't able to successfully get it working :(.