# Can Gulp be modularized?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I hope I'm close with this, it's starting to get really frustrating.

I've asked this before: [Is it possible to setup Gulp in a distributed fashion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949035/is-it-possible-to-setup-gulp-in-a-distributed-fashion)

...but I'm still not quite able to get it to work.

---

I've created a **[gist](https://gist.github.com/willpracht/4ec57962254c3470af22)** with the two files I'm working with.

*my-gulp* is installed via `npm`.

It's hitting `my-gulp/gulpfile.js` just fine, but I'm getting the following output:

```
> gulp
READING MY-GULP/GULPFILE.JS
CWD:  /Users/will/projects/my-app
[15:49:11] Using gulpfile ~/projects/my-app/gulpfile.js
[15:49:11] Task 'default' is not in your gulpfile
[15:49:11] Please check the documentation for proper gulpfile formatting
```

If I had to take a guess, it's something to do with the *cwd* being the root of the app, however I would assume it would error long before making an attempt to load a task (**this fails when attempting to run any task, btw, not just default**).

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm really at a blocker here :(.